# Внедрение кода во Flash

Tags: flash, внедрение

На одном сайте есть небольшая флешка. Я её скачал, декомпилировал (Sothink SWF Decompiler) и разобрал необходимые участки кода. Теперь нужно написать свой код, который будет инициализироваться вместе с запуском флешки. Мой код будет вызывать некоторые функции из уже готовых (симулирование кликов и нажатий клавиш) в определенном порядке. Написание кода - уже вторая задача. Допустим, у меня уже есть код. Как мне сделать, чтобы он запускался с загрузкой флешки и мог получить доступ к уже готовым функциям и методам? 
[Читал это](http://habrahabr.ru/post/127110/) и другие статьи, но не совсем до конца разобрался. Разжуйте, пожалуйста. Очень надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Секрет тут в прописывании в файле mm.cfg:

- Windows: C:\Documents and Settings\username\mm.cfg
- Windows 7 x64: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\mm.cfg
- Windows 7 x86: C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash\mm.cfg
- OSX: /Library/Application Support/Macromedia/mm.cfg
- Linux: home/username/mm.cfg

Прописываем путь к своему файлу, он будет загружаться при старте каждой swf'ки:

> PreloadSWF=c:\temp\MonsterConnector.swf

В исходниках ничего править не надо, нужно получить объект, у которого вы собираетесь вызывать методы и менять свойства... Декомпиляция нужна только для получения информации о классах и их методах и свойствах, а не для того чтоб внутрь код вписывать.

ЗЫ С монстром поиграть в их game тоже не помешает для понимания процесса.

Answer (score 0):

Найдите точку входа и туда пропишите свой код, в чем проблема-то? Обычно это где-нибудь в Application.applicationComplete, либо какие-нибудь другие события типа COMPLETE или INIT.

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, как это сделать. В этом и есть моя проблема.

Comment: А как без понимания того, как запускается и в каком порядке исполняется приложение Вы собираетесь с ним что-то сделать? Я подредактировал ответ, посмотрите, и уточните - приложение на AS2 или AS3?

Comment: Приложение на AS3.
Точка входа - это откуда начинается приложение? Самая главная функция? Я думаю, найти ее - не проблема (ну, по крайней мере, решаема). А как приписать туда свой код? В этом суть проблемы.